# Selecting default option in Angular generated dropdown

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, default

I have the following code:

```
<select ng-model="sortYear">
    <option value="all">All Years</option>
    <option ng-repeat="article in news | orderObjectBy:'year':true | unique: 'year'" value="{{article.year}}">{{article.year}}</option>
</select>
```

Which works perfectly. I've even got `sortYear` bound at a different point on the page, and it's connected fine, etc.

My problem is, when I get to the page, I want the default, prechosen selection to be the top actual year, not "All Years". I've tried a couple things:

1) I set $scope.sortYear in my controller. I know it's setting it since the bound `sortYear` later in the page is showing up just fine on the initial load.

2) I tried using ng-init to set it to a year explicitly, as well as tried the `ng-init="sortYear = getCurYear()"` where I defined a function getCurYear in the controller (and verified that I was actually hitting that function and setting/returning what I thought I should be) but nada.

What am I missing?

Comment: You really should use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of ngRepeat for selects.

Comment: so, in the initial select tag I would have ng-options="article in news | orderObjectBy:'year':true | unique: 'year'" ? Would that set my default?

Comment: Assuming your `sortYear` was set correctly it should.

Comment: It didn't work. :( I know sortYear is set correctly since it's being used elsewhere, but using the ng-options didn't set the default. It still uses the top value of "All Years"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-value` in option tag with `ng-repeat` like

```
<option ng-value="article.year" ng-repeat="article in news | orderObjectBy:'year':true | unique: 'year'">{{article.year}}</option>
```